# How do I calculate runtime complexity of the following JavaScript algorithm?

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, space-complexity

Below is a simple program to merge 2 arrays. I have used two different ways to solve this problem. How do I calculate runtime complexity, if possible space complexity too, of both these versions? Thanks in advance!

```js
let A = [1, 2, 3];
let B = [2, 3 , 4, 5];

// VERSION: 1
//let C = A.concat(B.filter( item => {return A.indexOf(item) < 0;} ));

// VERSION: 2
let C = [...new Set([...A,...B])];

// result:
console.log(C);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is lies within a term called Big O Notation. You can find detailed articles below.

In addition, you can use functional programming tools Ramda.js that achieve the same result which is getting the uniq numbers.

```
let A = [1, 2, 3];
let B = [2, 3 , 4, 5];
const concat = R.concat(A,B);
const result = R.uniq(concat);

console.log(result);
```

[For example](http://jsbin.com/poviqegubu/edit?js,console)

[Time Complexity](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/time-complexity-big-o-notation-1a4310c3ee4b)
[Big O Notation](https://medium.com/cesars-tech-insights/big-o-notation-javascript-25c79f50b19b)